# How to save txt on custom path

Tags: java, path

I have a code that saves a textfile, but the path of that textfile and the name are hardcoded.

How can i make that the user select his/her own path and the name of the file?

```
                int[][] sudokuNumbers = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    try (
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\Proyecto4.3\\output.txt"));) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sudokuNumbers.length; i++) {
            String s= "";
            for (int j = 0; j < sudokuNumbers[i].length; j++) {
                s+= "|" + sudokuNumbers[i][j] + "|";
            }
            output.println(s);
        }
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: save the path in one string and the name in the other then concat them and send the result as a parameter to new File ?

Comment: There are few ways to achieve that. Do you want to take file from command line or from UI?

Comment: i know that the path have to be on one variable, what i want is like when you download something and it displays a window that make you select the place and the name

Answer (score 0):

The task is relatively easy to carry out however you will need a couple methods to assist you. If a User is to supply a custom path (specific for them-self) then you will need to ensure that the path will be created so that it exists before the file is created and written to. Another thing to consider is that there may also be a requirement of Permissions to be granted to the application so as to carry out the task within the local file system (if this is where the file is to be created) or wherever else.

Obviously you will need to provide a means for the User to supply a path and file name. The best way to do this in my opinion is with a Folder Chooser dialog. The reason I say this is because it's not nearly as prone to mistakes (spelling, system format, etc.) as it would be if the User completely typed in the desired path and file name. Basically, the less control you give the User to the local file system the better off your application will be. Creating a folder (directory) based on the User Name within a preset file system location and utilizing a User name and date/time for file names is relatively common and can be all auto-generated, this eliminates the possibility of any file system errors. If possible, your application should maintain full control of such a task but understandably this can not always be the case for specific applications where User interaction with the file system is a requirement due to the fact that it's sole functionality is based on such interaction. For example, a File System Explorer where creating, cutting, copying, pasting, deleting, and editing of files and folders is its allowable purpose.

To demonstrate what I'm talking about I have quickly created a small Java runnable you can play with to see how the provided custom methods work. The code is well commented so that you can understand what is going on. Unfortunately all the commenting makes the code file look large when in fact it isn't if you were to remove them.

For simplicity, when we run the provided little console application it first asks for a User's Name. This Users Name will serve two specific purposes.

> **1)** It will be used to create a specific Folder for that particular User only.
>
> **2)** When a file is saved the file name will start with the User's name and then be followed with date/time data and finally contain the
>   ".txt" file name extension.

Again, just for example purposes, as soon as a User enters his/her name into the console a Folders Selection dialog window will be displayed so that a main folder location can be selected where Users sub-folders will be created in and ultimately the Users data files will be saved under his/her folder name.

The file data is automatically saved once the home folder is selected and the console indicates of success once completed. Our little console application then simply ends.

Here is the Java runnable:

```
package choosefolder;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ChooseFolder {
    // Declare & initialize required String variables.
    // These are global to the entire Class. 
    private static String userName = "";
    private static String savePath = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Setup a Scanner to get User input from console.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask for and get the Users Name and convert it to lowercase
        // so as to maintain nameing consistency. No sense having "John Doe"
        // one day and "john Doe" the next. This would consider 2 different 
        // Users since the second name has a lowercase "j" in "John" and 
        // therefore create two separate folder. Converting all supplied names
        // to lowercase eliminates this problem.
        while (userName.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter User Name:");
            userName = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }

        // Open a Folders selection dialog window and allow for
        // selection of a home folder where all Users saved files 
        // will be saved. Once we get the selected folder we then
        // add the Users name to the path and create it.
        savePath = openFoldersDialog("", "Select Home Folder To Save User Folders & File In...") + "\\" + userName;

        // Create a special path just for the Users Name (ie: C:\My Files\John Doe\).
        if (!createPath(savePath)) {
            // If false was returnd from the createPath() method
            // then there was an error while creating the path.
            // Read console output to get the Error.
            System.out.println("\n\u001B[31mError creating Users Save Path! Exiting...\u001B[39;49m");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Get the local date & time so we can add it to 
        // our file namewhen its created.
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        // Create the new file path & file name. This will be the path
        // and file name where our Users data will be saved. We take the 
        // Users path e created and then add the file name to the end. The
        // file name consists of the supplied User's name, the date/time and
        // the .txt file name extension. Unwanted characters are also removed
        // from the Date/Time. So, our path may look something like: 
        //       C:\My Files\John Doe-20160419T155758107.txt
        String filePathAndName = savePath + "\\" + userName + "-" + 
                                 dateTime.toString().replace("-", "").
                                 replace(":", "").replace(".", "") + ".txt";

        // Here is your code. This is the data saved to file....
        int[][] sudokuNumbers = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        try (
            // Notice the filePathAndName variable which we declared and initialized above.
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(filePathAndName));) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sudokuNumbers.length; i++) {
                String s= "";
                for (int j = 0; j < sudokuNumbers[i].length; j++) {
                    s+= "|" + sudokuNumbers[i][j] + "|";
                }
                output.println(s);
            }
            output.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
        finally {
            // Notify in console of success.
            System.out.println("\n\u001B[34mFile Saved SUCCESSFULLY in:\n\u001B[39;49m" + filePathAndName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens a Folder (directory) selection dialog window. All parameters for this method are optional but if you supply 
     * something to the last parameter then you must supply something to the parameters preceding it even if it's a null
     * string ("") (see usage examples below)
     * 
     * Example Usage:
     * 
     *          openFolderDialog();                                  //Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog("C:\\");                            //Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog("", "Select The Folder You Need");  //Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog("", "", "Select Folder");           //Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog("", "", "");                        //Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog( , "Your Folders, "Select Folder"); //Not Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog( , , "Select Folder");              //Not Allowed
     *          openFolderDialog("C:\\", "Your Folders, );           //Not Allowed
     * 
     * I think you get the idea here.
     * 
     * @param dialogOptions OPTIONAL - 3 String Type Parameters
     *    startPath           - String - Default is the running applications' home folder. The path
     *                          supplied here tells the dialog where to start displaying folders from.
     *                          If you just want to use default but would like to supply something to
     *                          the other optional parameters then just supply a null string ("") here.
     * 
     *    dialogTitle         - String - Dialog Window Title - Default is "Select Folder...". You can 
     *                          supply whatever title you like for the dialog window.
     * 
     *    openButtonCaption - String - The Select Button Caption - Default is "Select". You can supply 
     *                          whatever you like for a button caption and it can be more than one word
     *                          but do keep in mind that the button increases in length to accommodate the
     *                          the supplied string.
     * 
     * @return The selected Folder (directory) full path as string. Returns Null is nothing was selected.
     */
    public static String openFoldersDialog(String... dialogOptions) {
        String startPath = "";
        try {
            startPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}

        String dialogTitle = "Select Folder...";
        String openButtonCaption = "Select";

        if (dialogOptions.length != 0) { 
            if (dialogOptions.length >= 1) { 
                if (!dialogOptions[0].isEmpty()) { startPath = dialogOptions[0]; } 
            }
            if (dialogOptions.length >= 2) { 
                if (!dialogOptions[1].isEmpty()) { dialogTitle = dialogOptions[1]; } 
            }
            if (dialogOptions.length == 3) { 
                if (!dialogOptions[2].isEmpty()) { openButtonCaption = dialogOptions[2]; } 
            }
        }

        File sp = new File(startPath);
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(sp);

        //Remove the "Files Type:" combo box and label from dialog.
        removeJFCFilesTypeComponent(fc);

        fc.setDialogTitle(dialogTitle);
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        fc.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int userSelection = fc.showDialog(null, openButtonCaption);  //.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String f = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            return f;
        }
        return null;
    }   

    /**
     * Removes the Filter ComboBox from the supplied JFileChooser object.
     * This helps make the JFileChooser dialog window look more like a 
     * folder selection dialog.
     * @param filechooser The object name of the JFileChooser object.
     */
    public static void removeJFCFilesTypeComponent(Container filechooser) {
        Component[] components = filechooser.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JComboBox) {
                Object sel = ((JComboBox) component).getSelectedItem();
                if (sel.toString().contains("AcceptAllFileFilter")) {
                    component.setVisible(false);
                    // OR
                    //con.remove(component);
                }
            }
            if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                String text = ((JLabel) component).getText();
                if (text.equals("Files of Type:")) {
                    component.setVisible(false);
                    // OR
                    //con.remove(component);
                }
            }
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                removeJFCFilesTypeComponent((Container) component);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the supplied path into the local file system if it doesn't already exist. You must 
     * make sure permissions are properly in place before using this method otherwise the path may
     * not be created within the file system.
     * @param pathString The path to create (must not include a file name). Will not create path if it already exists.
     * @return Boolean True if successful and Boolean False if not.
     */
    public static boolean createPath(String pathString) {
        if (pathString.isEmpty()) { return false; }
        if (doesFolderExist(pathString)) { return true; }

        try {
            File foldersToMake = new File(pathString);
            foldersToMake.mkdirs();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            System.out.println("*** CreatePath() - Exception Encountered:\n*** " + ex.getMessage()); 
            return false; 
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method simply return boolean true or false if the supplied path exists.
     * @param folderPathString (String) The full path to check. No File Name is allowed 
     * to be in this path.
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean doesFolderExist(String folderPathString) {
        boolean tf = false;
        try {
            if (folderPathString.isEmpty() || "".equals(folderPathString)) { return tf; }
            File f = new File(folderPathString);
            if(f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) { tf = true; }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("*** DoesFolderExist() - Exception Encountered:\n*** " + e.getMessage());
            tf = false; 
        }
        return tf;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you (and others).